# Calculate date then adjust if weekend or holiday

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to create a formula that calculates a deadline date using four variables:
*StartDate, Over2%Date, Percentage, Currency*

- If *Percentage* < 2%, calculate (*StartDate* + 120)
- If *Percentage* >= 2%, calculate the lesser of (*StartDate* + 120) and (*Over2%Date* + 30)
- The resulting date cannot fall on a weekend or a holiday. Days should be subtracted until a valid working day is found.
- The range containing the list of holidays will vary depending on *Currency*

**Example:**

```
StartDate = 01 March 2021;  Over2%Date = 05 March 2021;  Percentage = 3%;  Currency = "EUR"

Percentage > 0.02   [therefore test:]   Over2%Date + 30  =  04 April 2021    
04 April 2021 is a Sunday   [therefore test:]   02 April 2021    
02 April 2021 is a holiday for EUR   [therefore test:]   01 April 2021    
Not a weekend, not a holiday    >>>>    function = 01 April 2021
```

**The problem:**

I tried some code but Excel returns value errors.  I think the problem lies with getting VBA to recognise the dates, in format: "DD MMM", to even begin the calculation.  I tried referring to the date variables as dates and as integers.

I also tried commenting out the parts that reference holidays and nothing changes so, while I'm sure that's also broken, it's not the only issue.

```vb
Function DEADLINE(SD As Date, OD As Date, PCT As Double, CCY As String) As Date
    Dim TEST As Date, HRANGE As Range, VALID As Boolean
    VALID = False
    If PCT = "" Then DEADLINE = ""
    If PCT >= 0.02 And (OD - SD) < 90 Then
        TEST = OD + 30
    Else: TEST = SD + 120
    End If
    If CCY = "EUR" Then
        HRANGE = Range("Holidays!A2:A60")
    Else: HRANGE = Range("Holidays!B2:B60")
        ' Select range to cross-check holidays
    End If
    If Weekday(TEST) = 1 Then TEST = TEST - 2
    If Weekday(TEST) = 7 Then TEST = TEST - 1
    ' Check if weekend
    Do Until VALID = True
        ' If holiday, subtract 1 and retry
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(HRANGE, TEST) = 0 Then
    VALID = True
        Else: TEST = TEST - 1
        End If
        If Weekday(TEST) = 1 Then TEST = TEST - 2
        If Weekday(TEST) = 7 Then TEST = TEST - 1
        ' Re-check weekend
    Loop
    DEADLINE = TEST
End Function
```

Comment: At a first look, you're missing a `Set` for your range variables. It'll be easier to debug if you call this function from a subroutine, instead of from a cell (as a UDF).

Comment: Why VBA? This can be done with worksheet functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Function DEADLINE(SD As Date, OD As Date, PCT As Double, CCY As String) As Date
    Dim HRANGE As Range
    Dim DT As Date

'set holiday range
Select Case CCY
    Case "EUR"
        Set HRANGE = Range("EUR") 'presume this  is a named range on the worksheet
    'Case "USD"
        'Set HRANGE = Range("USD"
    'etc
End Select

'Calculate deadline
DT = SD + 120
If PCT >= 0.02 Then _
    DT = IIf(DT > OD + 30, OD + 30, DT)
    
'Adjust for weekend/holidays

DEADLINE = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(DT + 1, -1, HRANGE)

End Function
```

As a worksheet function without VBA:

```
=WORKDAY(IF(Percent<2%,StartDate+120,MIN(StartDate+120,Over2+30))+1,-1,INDIRECT(Currency))
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh! I'd completely forgotten the native WORKDAY function could be used with custom holidays.  Thanks so much :)